# Firestore returns a Dictionary<String, Any> but I need the values as a String

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase to get Google Cloud Vision Optical Character Recognition on an image then putting that information into a Firestore database, however when I pull the data from Firestore it is of type Dictionary. I need the values to be in a String so I can manipulate them however I can't seem to cast something of type Any to a String. I can put the values into an array but it is still an array of Any type. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
    db.collection("imagedata").document(puzzletest.name!).addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard let document = documentSnapshot else{
            print("error")
            return
        }
        guard let data = document.data() else{
            print("empty")
            return
        }
        let arrayofres = Array(data.values)

        print(type(of:arrayofres))
    }
```

Here is the data I am trying to query:

**Image of database**:

[image: Screen Shot]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you are getting from Firestore.  Do you just need to use the Dictionary Key to then return the Dictionary Value cast to a string?

Comment: The dictionary its returns has only one key and one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `string` from the `dictionary` values as below,

```
let string = data.values.compactMap({ $0 as? String}).reduce("", +)
```